# how to push data to grid in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, wijmo

here I created sample program for employee list using wijmo grid, here my problem is i m not able to push the data in gird, 
Note: error shows push undefined 
Thanks in advance........................................

```js
angular.module('app', ['wj']);



'use strict';

// declare app module
var app = angular.module('app');

// controller
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  data = [];
  
  $scope.save=function(reg)
   { 
  var obj = [reg]; 
    
  $scope.data = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(obj);
    }

    // create the filter and expose it to scope for customization
    $scope.initialized = function (s, e) {
        var flex = s;
        $scope.filter = new wijmo.grid.filter.FlexGridFilter(flex);
        $scope.downloadsColumnFilterType = wijmo.grid.filter.FilterType.Condition;
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.filter.filterChanging.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter changing');
        });
        $scope.filter.filterChanged.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter changed');
        });
        $scope.filter.filterApplied.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter applied');
        });
    }

   

    // filters are localizable
 
    // invalidate all Wijmo controls
    // using a separate function to handle strange IE9 scope issues
 
    $scope.data = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(data);

     
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <!-- Wijmo -->
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.grid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.grid.filter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
    <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.input.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
    <link href="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/styles/vendor/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Wijmo-Angular interop -->
    <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
    
    
  </head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
 
    
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>First Name</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="reg.fname">  </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="reg.lname">  </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Midle Name</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="reg.mname">  </td>
        </tr>
      
       <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" ng-click=save(reg)> </td>
      
        </tr>
      
      
    </table>
  
  
        <wj-flex-grid
            style="height:300px"
            initialized="initialized(s, e)"
            items-source="data">
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="ID" binding="id"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="fname" binding="fname" format='MMM/dd/yyyy'></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="lname" binding="lname" format="t"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="mname" binding="mname"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                
        </wj-flex-grid>
      
        
         
         
    </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define newItemCreator function, that takes no parameters:

```
.controller("appCtrl", function ($scope) {

  var data = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView([]);

  // here
  data.newItemCreator = function() { 
    var item = {};
    item = angular.copy($scope.reg);
    return item;
  };

  $scope.data = data;

  // create the filter and expose it to scope for customization
  $scope.initialized = function (s, e) {
      var flex = s;
      $scope.filter = new wijmo.grid.filter.FlexGridFilter(flex);
      $scope.downloadsColumnFilterType = wijmo.grid.filter.FilterType.Condition;
      $scope.$apply();
      $scope.filter.filterChanging.addHandler(function () {
          console.log('filter changing');
      });
      $scope.filter.filterChanged.addHandler(function () {
          console.log('filter changed');
      });
      $scope.filter.filterApplied.addHandler(function () {
          console.log('filter applied');
      });
  };

});
```

And use addNew() method on your button:

```
<td><button type="button" ng-click=data.addNew()>Save</button></td>
```

Comment: Thanks @ Slava N, but textbox data not showing the grid ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Is that answer doesn't work for you? I get this result ([picture](http://s10.postimg.org/cy6a8zrjt/image.png)). Is your result differs from that? [Here is](http://freetexthost.com/gs3nl4uw52) full source code.